# constructor parameter, accept pointer to const only when instance is const

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a class:

```
class A{
    B* b;
public:
    A(B* pb):b(pb){}
}
```

And I make sure const method of `A` never modify the object pointed by `b`. So that it is safe to hold `B const*` when instance of `A` is const.

```
B const b;
A a(&b); // compile error
A const ca(&b); // compile error too. How can I allow this one
```

Comment: You have to have two versions of `A`: a mutable `A` and a `const_A`. This is the approach taken by the STL iterators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is **impossible**—constructors can’t even *tell* if the object is (going to be) `const`, let alone control overload resolution with the information.

The standard workaround (often used for iterators) is to make `A` a **template** (even if it only ever has two specializations) and use `A<const B>` to handle that case.  Yes, this is pretty poor: partly because it can delay some diagnostics, but more because there’s no automatic conversion from `A<B>` (nor can a `const A<const B>&` bind to an `A<B>`).  The good news is that this works without any special effort even when `A` has methods that do **mutate** `b` (which are often `const` in this formulation); they won’t be instantiated unless used.